# Unable to loop through json data using foreach()

Tags: php, json, foreach

I'm using an API to retrieve a json file, that I then want to echo out onto my webpage.

I am able to echo the data individually, like so :

```
echo $json2['result']['reviews'][0]['author_name'];
```

However, as soon as I try to loop through the data with a foreach loop(), i get the error:

```
Warning: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\cw\tester.php on line 36
Array
Warning: Attempt to read property "result" on array in C:\xampp\htdocs\cw\tester.php on line 38

Warning: Attempt to read property "reviews" on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\cw\tester.php on line 38

Warning: foreach() argument must be of type array|object, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\cw\tester.php on line 38
```

I'm sure its simple as json isn't too complicated, but I can't get it to work, as I don't understand what my problem is.

this is the for loop I tried to create:

```
foreach ($json2->result->reviews as $my_data){
        foreach ($my_data -> author_name as $names){
            echo $names . '<br>';
        }
    }
```

and this is the json file (I want to grab data from 'reviews'):

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "result" : {
      "address_components" : [
         {
            "long_name" : "Antrim Road",
            "short_name" : "Antrim Rd",
            "types" : [ "route" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "Belfast",
            "short_name" : "Belfast",
            "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "Newtownabbey",
            "short_name" : "Newtownabbey",
            "types" : [ "postal_town" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "Belfast",
            "short_name" : "Belfast",
            "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "Northern Ireland",
            "short_name" : "Northern Ireland",
            "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "United Kingdom",
            "short_name" : "GB",
            "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "BT36 7PN",
            "short_name" : "BT36 7PN",
            "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
         }
      ],
      "adr_address" : "\u003cspan class=\"street-address\"\u003eAntrim Road\u003c/span\u003e, \u003cspan class=\"extended-address\"\u003eBelfast\u003c/span\u003e, \u003cspan class=\"locality\"\u003eNewtownabbey\u003c/span\u003e \u003cspan class=\"postal-code\"\u003eBT36 7PN\u003c/span\u003e, \u003cspan class=\"country-name\"\u003eUK\u003c/span\u003e",
      "business_status" : "OPERATIONAL",
      "formatted_address" : "Antrim Rd, Belfast, Newtownabbey BT36 7PN, UK",
      "formatted_phone_number" : "028 9077 6277",
      "geometry" : {
         "location" : {
            "lat" : 54.6577821,
            "lng" : -5.943665699999999
         },
         "viewport" : {
            "northeast" : {
               "lat" : 54.65913108029149,
               "lng" : -5.942316719708497
            },
            "southwest" : {
               "lat" : 54.6564331197085,
               "lng" : -5.945014680291502
            }
         }
      },
      "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/v1/png_71/generic_business-71.png",
      "international_phone_number" : "+44 28 9077 6277",
      "name" : "Belfast Zoo",
      "photos" : [
         {
            "height" : 1243,
            "html_attributions" : [
               "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/111863060002111236588\"\u003eBelfast Zoo\u003c/a\u003e"
            ],
            "photo_reference" : "ATtYBwLPDngDqoLqrE-KZnFdp94V6uH2rOa-x4B2A7GVXOKD7raGPWiKtjNeDKEDpXrvbl9hPrjiE82RrHy-WFTyaIM51I7lE4f_gQavJlNtEcI8QCyNlgXdNbdubkFBTwOQpYQojvtcLavYu6RIHmiAQA8DnO3IQpX7pd3OIUC2drtfN85w",
            "width" : 1776
         },
         {
            "height" : 2988,
            "html_attributions" : [
               "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/100936618118839321951\"\u003eAmanda Lewis\u003c/a\u003e"
            ],
            "photo_reference" : "ATtYBwI4nDTtt9wy2B18qwRhRrAd90Z24tQL5KpKDYw8UqHLbMXeazhIQzG0B72gNJ5qASZT3lVzw9IQ8789ovoqmfvhBU9biLUSjYWDFZRUz-UBIAvc-7ma69soGhze5ysjzg9K67e14axna-npfP0A64cc2v5pHO14hph0l8uBRovb4tnL",
            "width" : 5312
         },
         {
            "height" : 2988,
            "html_attributions" : [
               "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/116390912159770135890\"\u003eBeti Na\u003c/a\u003e"
            ],
            "photo_reference" : "ATtYBwIBVFK2xPo7SoaT35yaxTvJo27782EJWXiLAlB7MuA3XHAbRd_DfJ7T6ZBZLVmpeyCO7GgyF06kkPtDak58HlGEup-IAyGXoCS6byofWqzqjjwvPx_FmN5tY2XfSU4Ocvs-UYyxnCA9T0q00egfJCL92XTMLHib5TDqQeAQY3r6pMKS",
            "width" : 5312
         },
         {
            "height" : 9248,
            "html_attributions" : [
               "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/106644795451552578979\"\u003eMatthew mcmullan\u003c/a\u003e"
            ],
            "photo_reference" : "ATtYBwL1S6nVnplt3cRoJgsifwFdNo6fgcgd2GLpJqNuYvCdWBCMkvXNcFMiQ07OOzptgfsiYedU0xgUzG5D_VRXVPddqwgZQa0A4uBXoX43GFAU9rh3AB0u8MKY0M_1FB56GwVBEToT7rlShjLS5_KI1hOowB4ZdptMI_twgQwkzcEmIkg0",
            "width" : 6936
         },
         {
            "height" : 2988,
            "html_attributions" : [
               "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/116390912159770135890\"\u003eBeti Na\u003c/a\u003e"
            ],
            "photo_reference" : "ATtYBwKFyQSrzrvX0X4tDu26wN10cgbo5w6JIlRQTWC4ttbAboV7ICKCuLWVazvoTdpBT1UpKGTsQHyVoZhC5f-1CBYtwZQCuTrOyGy8at0zsHW9ENLjq5q_zvB9LCHdgCUWMgWnBRzlYonNYCkPzRu-qORlJSX8X66-miqdbtXUFxMz-o3H",
            "width" : 5312
         },
         {
            "height" : 3823,
            "html_attributions" : [
               "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/116284097622909280304\"\u003eBrian Cunningham\u003c/a\u003e"
            ],
            "photo_reference" : "ATtYBwJwf5rfaz8OqJ4AbQMgxKU3rKUf-4O6_Z6ME6vuZ5X6zgaSKdqvN_IxHuYqZIZWtPBlTFeYs4AzcH9oXWHQjrKdX5nGXelND-OoMe_Srp5pgGwmEr2f3TVQFktQAyv3NBA5l4JcBiKlb9wR_EueGaiEI6aM6VQobg6ab8CTXTGQclB7",
            "width" : 5735
         },
         {
            "height" : 4000,
            "html_attributions" : [
               "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/109005734355336105418\"\u003eWilliam Young\u003c/a\u003e"
            ],
            "photo_reference" : "ATtYBwKlMZ9zSIi-AkC5M9nyMiOo3ly_-NtKqrFpz5A-_YFXyEc-Mn9APluh__SgUHPwgbNkZ27BjUYtK2Deb5MHax6yICyIC9RzZGOD4AY_F1pSPUXwwkMwuW66JMx_ZsgW-GpkJKo9m89Cua_mFBOfwrvxSpm66lwfpuQUsUz2fibwMKEQ",
            "width" : 2723
         },
         {
            "height" : 3024,
            "html_attributions" : [
               "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/100719597211687837516\"\u003eJonathan Kelly\u003c/a\u003e"
            ],
            "photo_reference" : "ATtYBwJtrdU_MSyxj8Tzh-wt4fJeI9xnMBJSYus2rCCBRhVb1z64xhreHcSB3-QLRvoVS-XYSYLMhEyvtIBdsiNowQaBBHJEAUXcWtpsyvRCYjZU8a9gr9SCJpmo_Wj42CJTxR65cKlGC7i5dEDgssPUqmRZug8B5AtjJ3tuzGUqIBKcNdjz",
            "width" : 4032
         },
         {
            "height" : 3024,
            "html_attributions" : [
               "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/104554106193648036788\"\u003eAjay Jose\u003c/a\u003e"
            ],
            "photo_reference" : "ATtYBwJzspaF2TTMtjQYmDJ1_IOJmjH6apJBqz9UJ8POUX1M8airOQja9pZQmrK0SONdFQUgTV-HXFI57sGHFmhetWxMilc5jPU_JcBQT6bhyX6Wqt21tbsV1GM9ySMXbYqMYwlSMBGrP9fiK32hbkxy7A5ecjX88QCYdvVUGqf2hbB8o2bM",
            "width" : 4032
         },
         {
            "height" : 3024,
            "html_attributions" : [
               "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/100719597211687837516\"\u003eJonathan Kelly\u003c/a\u003e"
            ],
            "photo_reference" : "ATtYBwKqikSfsSeOGFFpSIx1g9O1iDMA3Xn_gf--hC2I9pJCOzDLFMkkLghF9Sr3j6kftlrCx8SSVhEPuZOZXxBOanl3qUh4UA5bvV7QTt3tD5Qje9Tnkd4319h-91dBZshFvd3y8rJb5WK_98bzc06DMIjCtJOPcQ3j1jV0Pr-DpGsPOH0-",
            "width" : 4032
         }
      ],
      "place_id" : "ChIJ88iCe5inYUgRdeXmfCtuvu4",
      "plus_code" : {
         "compound_code" : "M354+4G Belfast, UK",
         "global_code" : "9C6PM354+4G"
      },
      "rating" : 4.3,
      "reference" : "ChIJ88iCe5inYUgRdeXmfCtuvu4",
      "reviews" : [
         {
            "author_name" : "Karen Hoad",
            "author_url" : "https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/103129952317107981705/reviews",
            "language" : "en",
            "profile_photo_url" : "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-OkGM8wAyHz8/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/AMZuucn55YdMQZ1BX6ods-S34cieMQODrg/s128-c0x00000000-cc-rp-mo-ba5/photo.jpg",
            "rating" : 4,
            "relative_time_description" : "6 months ago",
            "text" : "Great place just not good when raining as the animals stay in",
            "time" : 1599236033
         },
         {
            "author_name" : "John Lee Ashworth",
            "author_url" : "https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/116452096322094109908/reviews",
            "language" : "en",
            "profile_photo_url" : "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-_ZpK7cdK1NI/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/AMZuuclmcdFSQNilc5MfhJ3m8rRqzAXO_A/s128-c0x00000000-cc-rp-mo/photo.jpg",
            "rating" : 3,
            "relative_time_description" : "6 months ago",
            "text" : "Love zoos, love animals, hate nothing but steep hills though",
            "time" : 1598880406
         },
         {
            "author_name" : "Clare",
            "author_url" : "https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/116989491220973031798/reviews",
            "language" : "en",
            "profile_photo_url" : "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GjK9VEovk8XRG41K9vVtu0SKRIHQdXp6Gb79opr_g=s128-c0x00000000-cc-rp-mo-ba2",
            "rating" : 2,
            "relative_time_description" : "5 months ago",
            "text" : "Very little animals to see.",
            "time" : 1600628749
         },
         {
            "author_name" : "Tammy 102",
            "author_url" : "https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/111672456708879530776/reviews",
            "language" : "en",
            "profile_photo_url" : "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-ngjoEXxeE8Q/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/AMZuucnTOkOTeq8ecWLEVbSs7UBnsUPmSQ/s128-c0x00000000-cc-rp-mo-ba3/photo.jpg",
            "rating" : 5,
            "relative_time_description" : "5 months ago",
            "text" : "To check prices",
            "time" : 1600610117
         },
         {
            "author_name" : "Mark Woonton",
            "author_url" : "https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/106800516570033737478/reviews",
            "language" : "en",
            "profile_photo_url" : "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GgnYZybrP-MTC4U45agdIlXMIFDIuH1v6roRuJAWQ=s128-c0x00000000-cc-rp-mo",
            "rating" : 5,
            "relative_time_description" : "6 months ago",
            "text" : "Amazing zoo, so much to see, a great day out",
            "time" : 1599993064
         }
      ],
      "types" : [ "zoo", "tourist_attraction", "point_of_interest", "establishment" ],
      "url" : "https://maps.google.com/?cid=17203308759660029301",
      "user_ratings_total" : 2714,
      "utc_offset" : 0,
      "vicinity" : "Antrim Road, Belfast",
      "website" : "http://www.belfastzoo.co.uk/"
   },
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Comment: The errors are trying *really hard* to tell you what's wrong. `Warning: Attempt to read property "result" on array` - you are reading a *property*, expecting an *object*, but you have an *array*. You have probably decoded your JSON as an associative array (second parameter to `json_decode` is set to `true`). So either decode as object (without the second parameter) or use array access instead of property access.

Comment: Okay that makes a lot of sense and is very helpful thank you!